# Need Regex expression to allow only either numbers or letters separated by comma and it should not allow alpha numeric

Tags: c#, regex

Need Regex expression to allow only either **numbers or letters separated by comma** and it should not allow *alpha numeric combinations* (like `"abc123"`).

Some examples:

```
Valid:

   123,abc 
   abc,123
   123,123
   abc,abc

Invalid:

   abc,abc123   
   abc133,abc 
   abc123,abc123
```

Comment: i find this site useful http://regexstorm.net/reference see what you can come up with

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Is `1,a,2,b` valid?

Comment: yes 1,a,2,b is valid

Comment: Something like this: `^[0-9a-zA-Z](,[0-9a-zA-Z])*$`

Comment: ^[0-9a-zA-Z](,[0-9a-zA-Z])*$ works fine.. u r a genius man  "Dmitry Bychenko"

Comment: I have updated requirement, pleaseee update ur valuable answers

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the title, and changed halfway through when you changed your mind. i think you should accept and answer then ask another question and this time try and research and figure (at least) a bit of it out your self

Comment: This site is not allowing me to add another question,so i have edited it.I am new to this site, so there were some errors after editing.From next time i will  do it correctly. Now i have edited the post correctly including title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since valid and invalid are *changed*, I've rewritten my answer from scratch.
The suggested pattern is

```
^(([0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z]+))(,(([0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z]+)))*$
```

Demo:

```
string[] tests = new string[] {
  "123,abc",
  "abc,123",
  "123,123",
  "abc,abc",

  "abc,abc123",
  "abc133,abc",
  "abc123,abc123",
   // More tests
  "123abc",       // invalid (digits first, then letters)
  "123",          // valid   (one item)
  "a,b,c,1,2,3",  // valid   (more than two items)  
  "1e4",          // invalid (floating point number)
  "1,,2",         // invalid (empty part)
  "-3",           // invalid (minus sign) 
  "۱۲۳",          // invalid (Persian digits)
  "число"         // invalid (Russian letters) 
};

string pattern = @"^(([0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z]+))(,(([0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z]+)))*$";

var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(item => $"{item,-20} : {(Regex.IsMatch(item, pattern) ? "valid" : "invalid")}"));

Console.WriteLine(report);
```

Outcome:

```
123,abc              : valid
abc,123              : valid
123,123              : valid
abc,abc              : valid
abc,abc123           : invalid
abc133,abc           : invalid
abc123,abc123        : invalid
123abc               : invalid
123                  : valid
a,b,c,1,2,3          : valid
1e4                  : invalid
1,,2                 : invalid
-3                   : invalid
۱۲۳                  : invalid
число                : invalid
```

Pattern's explanation:

```
^                         - string beginning (anchor)
([0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z]+)      - either group of digits (1+) or group of letters
(,(([0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z]+))) - fllowed by zero or more such groups
$                         - string ending (anchor)
```

Comment: ^[0-9a-zA-Z](,[0-9a-zA-Z])*$ works fine.. u r a genius man "Dmitry Bychenko"

Answer (score 0):

If you specify Dmitry Bychenkos regex with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` you can shrink it down to `Regex.IsMatch (test, @"^[0-9a-z](,[0-9a-z])*$",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Alternate way to check it w/o regex (performs worse):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var mydata = new[] {"1,3,4,5,1,3,a,s,r,3", "2, 4 , a", " 2,3,as"};


        // function that checks it- perfoms not as good as reges as internal stringarray
        // is build and analyzed
        Func<string,bool> isValid = 
            data => data.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(s => s.Trim())
            .All(aChar => aChar.Length == 1 && char.IsLetterOrDigit(aChar[0]));

        foreach (var d in mydata)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} => is {1}",d, isValid(d) ? "Valid" : "Invalid"));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1,3,4,5,1,3,a,s,r,3 => is Valid
2, 4 , a => is Valid
 2,3,as => is Invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

To match words separated by commas, where the words consist either of digits or of letters:

```
^(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)(,(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+))*$
```

*Explanation*

- `\d+` matches a string of at least one digit.
- `[a-zA-Z]` matches a string of at least one upper or lower case letter.
- `(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)` matches either a string of digits or a string of letters.

*C#*

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)(,(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+))*$");
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer but it is failing for 1,a,2,b, and abc,abc123

Comment: Ok, my bad. I tried to be clever with `(,|$)` so I did not have to duplicate the part of the expression that matches the words. But that also makes things rather complex. I fixed the problem with `1,a,2,b,`. I do not understand what is not working with `abc,abc123`. That should **not** match the regex, right?

Comment: Now with ur updated expression, everything works fine..thank uu